# How to implement enum with generics?

Tags: java, generics, interface, enums

I have a generic interface like this:

```
interface A<T> {
    T getValue();
}
```

This interface has limited instances, hence it would be best to implement them as enum values. The problem is those instances have different type of values, so I tried the following approach but it does not compile:

```
public enum B implements A {
    A1<String> {
        @Override
        public String getValue() {
            return "value";
        }
    },
    A2<Integer> {
        @Override
        public Integer getValue() {
            return 0;
        }
    };
}
```

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can't. Java doesn't allow generic types on enum constants. They are allowed on enum types, though:

```
public enum B implements A<String> {
  A1, A2;
}
```

What you could do in this case is either have an enum type for each generic type, or 'fake' having an enum by just making it a class:

```
public class B<T> implements A<T> {
    public static final B<String> A1 = new B<String>();
    public static final B<Integer> A2 = new B<Integer>();
    private B() {};
}
```

Unfortunately, they both have drawbacks.

Comment: This approach does not solve my problem unless I use `enum B implemts A<Object>`, which in turn makes the generic interface meaningless.

Comment: That's the point I'm trying to make - your problem can't be solved by using a single `Enum`.

Comment: Now at least I understand `enum` is not so suitable for my requirement. Thanks!

Comment: @Pokechu22 sounds good to me, especially when combined with the new proposal to allow primitives as type parameters.

Answer (score 43):

As Java developers designing certain APIs, we come across this issue frequently.  I was reconfirming my own doubts when I came across this post, but I have a verbose workaround to it:

```
// class name is awful for this example, but it will make more sense if you
//  read further
public interface MetaDataKey<T extends Serializable> extends Serializable
{
    T getValue();
}

public final class TypeSafeKeys
{
    static enum StringKeys implements MetaDataKey<String>
    {
        A1("key1");

        private final String value;

        StringKeys(String value) { this.value = value; }

        @Override
        public String getValue() { return value; }
    }

    static enum IntegerKeys implements MetaDataKey<Integer>
    {
        A2(0);

        private final Integer value;

        IntegerKeys (Integer value) { this.value = value; }

        @Override
        public Integer getValue() { return value; }
    }

    public static final MetaDataKey<String> A1 = StringKeys.A1;
    public static final MetaDataKey<Integer> A2 = IntegerKeys.A2;
}
```

At that point, you gain the benefit of being a truly constant `enum`eration value (and all of the perks that go with that), as well being an unique implementation of the `interface`, but you have the global accessibility desired by the `enum`.

Clearly, this adds verbosity, which creates the potential for copy/paste mistakes. You could  make the `enum`s `public` and simply add an extra layer to their access.

Designs that tend to use these features tend to suffer from brittle `equals` implementations because they are usually coupled with some other unique value, such as a name, which can be unwittingly duplicated across the codebase for a similar, yet different purpose.  By using `enum`s across the board, equality is a freebie that is immune to such brittle behavior.

The major drawback to such as system, beyond verbosity, is the idea of converting back and forth between the globally unique keys (e.g., marshaling to and from JSON).  If they're just keys, then they can be safely reinstantiated (duplicated) at the cost of wasting memory, but using what was previously a weakness--`equals`--as an advantage.

There is a workaround to this that provides global implementation uniqueness by cluttering it with an anonymous type per global instance:

```
public abstract class BasicMetaDataKey<T extends Serializable>
     implements MetaDataKey<T>
{
    private final T value;

    public BasicMetaDataKey(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public T getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    // @Override equals
    // @Override hashCode
}

public final class TypeSafeKeys
{
    public static final MetaDataKey<String> A1 =
        new BasicMetaDataKey<String>("value") {};
    public static final MetaDataKey<Integer> A2 =
        new BasicMetaDataKey<Integer>(0) {};
}
```

Note that each instance uses an anonymous implementation, but nothing else is needed to implement it, so the `{}` are empty.  This is both confusing and annoying, but it works if instance references are preferable and clutter is kept to a minimum, although it may be a bit cryptic to less experienced Java developers, thereby making it harder to maintain.

Finally, the only way to provide global uniqueness and reassignment is to be a little more creative with what is happening. The most common use for globally shared interfaces that I have seen are for MetaData buckets that tend to mix a lot of different values, with different types (the `T`, on a per key basis):

```
public interface MetaDataKey<T extends Serializable> extends Serializable
{
    Class<T> getType();
    String getName();
}

public final class TypeSafeKeys
{
    public static enum StringKeys implements MetaDataKey<String>
    {
        A1;

        @Override
        public Class<String> getType() { return String.class; }

        @Override
        public String getName()
        {
            return getDeclaringClass().getName() + "." + name();
        }
    }

    public static enum IntegerKeys implements MetaDataKey<Integer>
    {
        A2;

        @Override
        public Class<Integer> getType() { return Integer.class; }

        @Override
        public String getName()
        {
            return getDeclaringClass().getName() + "." + name();
        }
    }

    public static final MetaDataKey<String> A1 = StringKeys.A1;
    public static final MetaDataKey<Integer> A2 = IntegerKeys.A2;
}
```

This provides the same flexibility as the first option, and it provides a mechanism for obtaining a reference via reflection, if it becomes necessary later, therefore avoiding the need for instantiable later.  It also avoids a lot of the error prone copy/paste mistakes that the first option provides because it won't compile if the first method is wrong, and the second method does not need to change.  The only note is that you should ensure that the `enum`s meant to be used in that fashion are `public` to avoid anyone getting access errors because they do not have access to the inner `enum`; if you did not want to have those `MetaDataKey`s going across a marshaled wire, then keeping them hidden from outside packages could be used to automatically discard them (during marshaling, reflectively check to see if the `enum` is accessible, and if it is not, then ignore the key/value).  There is nothing gained or lost by making it `public` except providing two ways to access the instance, if the more obvious `static` references are maintained (as the `enum` instances are just that anyway).

I just wish that they made it so that `enum`s could extend objects in Java. Maybe in Java 9?

The final option does not really solve your need, as you were asking for values, but I suspect that this gets toward the actual goal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this workaround! Actually you don't need to use `enum`, just use anonymous inner classes, which is what I'm doing now.

Comment: No problem. The anonymous inner class is the middle example. I tend to avoid anonymous classes for maintainability (both compiled code becomes confusing with the `$1`, `$2` anonymous types and many developers will miss the reason for being an anonymous type), but it's definitely a valid and smaller approach.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer.  Thank you for your effort.

Comment: This is an old post, but can you summarize the costs and benefits of the implementations you provided? I'm having some trouble understanding why I would choose one over the others.

Answer (score 18):

*If* [JEP 301: Enhanced Enums](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/301) gets accepted, *then* you will be able to use syntax like this (taken from proposal):

```
enum Primitive<X> {
    INT<Integer>(Integer.class, 0) {
        int mod(int x, int y) { return x % y; }
        int add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
    },
    FLOAT<Float>(Float.class, 0f)  {
        long add(long x, long y) { return x + y; }
    }, ... ;

    final Class<X> boxClass;
    final X defaultValue;

    Primitive(Class<X> boxClass, X defaultValue) {
        this.boxClass = boxClass;
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that it has actually been withdrawn:  http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/301

Comment: @TiStrga where did you see that? The [latest message](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170351?focusedCommentId=14371268&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14371268) was from September and called it dead

Comment: @TiStrga on 2020-09-29 they wrote `we are now withdrawing this JEP`, the emails from December you are referring to are from December 2018. This JEP is clearly dead.

Comment: I misread that quite badly!  I've removed the misleading links; thank you.  Pity, this language feature would have cleaned up a considerable amount of code.

Answer (score 1):

By using this Java annotation processor https://github.com/cmoine/generic-enums, you can write this:

```java
import org.cmoine.genericEnums.GenericEnum;
import org.cmoine.genericEnums.GenericEnumParam;

@GenericEnum
public enum B implements A<@GenericEnumParam Object> {
    A1(String.class, "value"), A2(int.class, 0);

    @GenericEnumParam
    private final Object value;

    B(Class<?> clazz, @GenericEnumParam Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @GenericEnumParam
    @Override
    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The annotation processor will generate an enum `BExt` with hopefully all what you need!

if you prefer you can also use this syntax:

```java
import org.cmoine.genericEnums.GenericEnum;
import org.cmoine.genericEnums.GenericEnumParam;

@GenericEnum
public enum B implements A<@GenericEnumParam Object> {
    A1(String.class) {
        @Override
        public @GenericEnumParam Object getValue() {
            return "value";
        }
    }, A2(int.class) {
        @Override
        public @GenericEnumParam Object getValue() {
            return 0;
        }
    };

    B(Class<?> clazz) {
    }

    @Override
    public abstract @GenericEnumParam Object getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something simple like this, and checking in methods that receive `ObjectTypeEnum` and a typed parameter that the class matches the enum. You could also limit `T` so that it extends a specific interface if needed.

```
public enum ObjectTypeEnum {
  STRING(String.class);

  private final Class<?> objectClass;

  <T> ObjectTypeEnum(Class<T> objectClass) {

    this.objectClass = objectClass;
  }
}

public void call(ObjectTypeEnum objectType, Object objectData) {
  requireNonNull(objectType);
  requireNonNull(objectData);

  if (objectType.objectClass != objectData.getClass()) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a class with enum like behavior:

```
public class ENUM
{
    private static final Map<Class<? extends ENUM>, Integer> ordinals = new HashMap<>();
    
    private final Class<? extends ENUM> type;
    private final int ordinal;
    private String name;
    
    protected ENUM(Class<? extends ENUM> type)
    {
        this.type = type;
        if (!ordinals.containsKey(type)) ordinals.put(type, 0);
        ordinal = ordinals.get(type);
        ordinals.put(type, ordinal + 1);
    }
    
    protected static void INIT(Class<? extends ENUM> type)
    {
        try
        {
            for (Field field : type.getDeclaredFields())
            {
                int mod = field.getModifiers();
                if (type.isAssignableFrom(field.getType()) && Modifier.isPublic(mod) && Modifier.isStatic(mod) && Modifier.isFinal(mod))
                {
                    ENUM fieldValue = (ENUM)field.get(null);
                    fieldValue.name = field.getName();
                }
            }
            ordinals.remove(type);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    public int ordinal()
    {
        return ordinal;
    }
    public String name()
    {
        return name;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return ordinal;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj instanceof ENUM || type.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass()))) return false;
        ENUM other = (ENUM)obj;
        return ordinal == other.ordinal;
    }
    
    public static <T extends ENUM> T[] values(Class<T> type)
    {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Field field : type.getDeclaredFields())
        {
            int mod = field.getModifiers();
            if (type.isAssignableFrom(field.getType()) && Modifier.isPublic(mod) && Modifier.isStatic(mod) && Modifier.isFinal(mod))
            {
                try
                {
                    //noinspection unchecked
                    list.add((T)field.get(null));
                }
                catch (IllegalAccessException e)
                {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                }
            }
        }
        list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(ENUM::ordinal));
        //noinspection unchecked
        return list.toArray((T[])Array.newInstance(type, list.size()));
    }
    public static <T extends ENUM> T valueOf(Class<T> type, String name)
    {
        if (name == null) throw new NullPointerException("Name is null");
        for (Field field : type.getDeclaredFields())
        {
            int mod = field.getModifiers();
            if (type.isAssignableFrom(field.getType()) && Modifier.isPublic(mod) && Modifier.isStatic(mod) && Modifier.isFinal(mod))
            {
                if (name.equals(field.getName()))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //noinspection unchecked
                        return (T)field.get(null);
                    }
                    catch (IllegalAccessException e)
                    {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No ENUM constant " + type.getName() + "." + name);
    }
}
```

And then you can create subclasses from it with all the functions of a standard Java class, like generics:

```
public static class GenericEnum<T> extends ENUM
{
    public static final GenericEnum<String> ONE = new GenericEnum<>("One");
    public static final GenericEnum<Integer> TWO = new GenericEnum<>(2);
    public static final GenericEnum<Boolean> THREE = new GenericEnum<>(false);
    
    static { ENUM.INIT(GenericEnum.class); }
    
    private final T genericObject;
    
    protected GenericEnum(T genericObject)
    {
        super(GenericEnum.class);
        this.genericObject = genericObject;
    }
    
    public T getGenericObject()
    {
        return genericObject;
    }
    
    public static GenericEnum<?>[] values()
    {
        return ENUM.values(GenericEnum.class);
    }
    public static GenericEnum<?> valueOf(String name)
    {
        return ENUM.valueOf(GenericEnum.class, name);
    }
}
```