# Clean code - Avoiding explicit type casts with collections built on generic data types

Tags: java, generics, refactoring, reusability

I am using a Map to read the rows from a spreadsheet and store its contents in the following way:

```
public class DocumentRow {

    private Map<Column, DocumentCell<?>> rowContents = new HashMap<>();

    private int rowNum;

    public DocumentCell<?> getValue(Column column) {
        return rowContents.get(column);
    }

    public void setValue(Column column, DocumentCell<?> value) {
        rowContents.put(column, value);
    }

    public DigitalDocument toDomainObject() {
        DomainObject domainObject = new DomainObject();
        domainObject.setTextValue((String) rowContents.get(TEXT_VALUE).getValue());
        domainObject.setNumericValue((int) rowContents.get(NUMERIC_VALUE).getValue());
        domainObject.setDateValue((LocalDate) rowContents.get(DATE_VALUE).getValue());
        return domainObject;
    }
}

public class DocumentCell<T> {
    private T value;
}

public enum Column {
    TEXT_VALUE("Text_Column_Name", DataType.STRING),
    NUMERIC_VALUE("Numeric_Column_Name", DataType.NUMBER),
    DATE_VALUE("Date_Column_Name", DataType.DATE);
}
```

(I have ommited some obvious classes for the sake of brevity)

The row values are provided as:

```
row.setValue(column, new DocumentCell<>(getDateCellValue(spreadSheetCell)));
```

Is there way this could be made cleaner so that I don't require these unchecked casts while constructing the domain object? Or a better way to design this?

Comment: It seems your `rowContents` only contain at most 3 values?

Comment: No, this is just an example. There are more than 10 of those.

Comment: How many values do you have in `enum Column`?

Comment: @AxelH They are 15 fields with a possibility of more additions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with enum is that you can't use generic types. You can see more about that in [How to implement enum with generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11490485/4391450).

First, we need to create an "enum-like" class with constants using generic types.

```
class Column<T> {
    public static final Column<String> TEXT_VALUE = new Column<>("Text_Column_Name", String.class);
    public static final Column<Number> NUMERIC_VALUE = new Column<>("Numeric_Column_Name", Number.class);
    public static final Column<Date> DATE_VALUE = new Column<>("Date_Column_Name", Date.class);

    String name;
    Class<T> clazz;

    private Column(String name, Class<T> clazz){
        this.name = name;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}
```

That way, we can secure the insertion of value in the map to match the type of `Column` with the method :

```
public <U> void setValue(Column<U> column, DocumentCell<U> value) {
    rowContents.put(column, value);
}
```

Example :

```
DocumentRow row = new DocumentRow();
row.setValue(Column.TEXT_VALUE, new DocumentCell<String>("asdf"));
row.setValue(Column.TEXT_VALUE, new DocumentCell<Integer>(4)); //Don't compile, can't set an `Integer` document cell into a `Column.TEXT_VALUE`
```

Now, we are sure that a value inserted for `Column.TEXT_VALUE` will hold a `String`, and the same for every `Column` constants.

Since we have insured the type during the insertion, we can be dirty and cast `DocumentCell<?>` from the map to the same type of `Column`:

```
public <U> U getValue(Column<U> column) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    DocumentCell<U> doc = (DocumentCell<U>) rowContents.get(column);
    return doc.getValue(column);
}
```

And a small example of the result :

```
String s = row.getValue(Column.TEXT_VALUE);
Integer i = row.getValue(Column.TEXT_VALUE); //DON'T COMPILE : `row.getValue` will return a value of the type define by `Column`, here a `String`
```

Complete usage example:

```
DocumentRow row = new DocumentRow();
row.setValue(Column.TEXT_VALUE, new DocumentCell<>("asdf"));
row.setValue(Column.NUMERIC_VALUE, new DocumentCell<>(4));
row.setValue(Column.DATE_VALUE, new DocumentCell<>(new Date()));

String s = row.getValue(Column.TEXT_VALUE);
Number i = row.getValue(Column.NUMERIC_VALUE);
Date d = row.getValue(Column.DATE_VALUE);
```

Note that in the last example, I didn't provides the type for `DocumentCell`, the compiler knows it will use the same a the `Column` parameter before.

And you can find the complete code on [this ideone](https://ideone.com/wVrKZ2) project.

---

Of course, we can drop the "enum-like" part and initialized the `Column` instance on need. All we need to do is set the constructor visible (not private at least) and we can create new "column type mappings"

```
Column<LocalDateTime> colDate = new Column<>("A new Date", LocalDateTime.class);
row.setValue(colDate , new DocumentCell<>(LocalDateTime.now()));
```