# Java enum method return generic type supplied in constructor?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I would like to have a generic return type for an enum method `getValue()`. The returned type should be the same as the one supplied in the constructor of the enum.

```
public enum ParameterType
{
    NUMBER(int.class),
    TEXT(String.class);

    private Class<?> classType;

    ParameterType(Class<?> _clazz)
    {
        classType = _clazz;
    }

    public <T> T getValue()
    {
        String a = "i am a text";
        int b = 42;

        return classType.cast(a);
        //return classType.cast(b);
    }
}
```

However, in this case the error is "cannot convert from capture #3 ? to T". Also, it is not possible to provide a generic "X" type on the enum itself which could be used for return types in case of classes.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where's `String a, int b` come from in real code?

Comment: What you're trying to do won't work. The best you can do is have the `getValue()` method return type `<? extends Class>` because the method (and the client) can't know any more information than that. Unless you actually tell the `getValue` method which return type to expect, but if the client code is able to tell it what the return value will be, then why does the client code need to call the method at all?

Comment: Looks like a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11490485 ?

Comment: In real code, `a` and `b` come from a parameter-injected dependency (after creating the enum itself) and depending the type of the enum (number vs text), the corresponding one is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Do forget about casting. Do redefine ‘getValue()’ for each enum constants.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with an enum, because all values in an enum have the same type.

To do this, you have to basically build the "enum" by hand:

```
public final class ParameterType<T>
{
  public static final ParameterType<Integer> NUMBER = new ParameterType<>(42);
  public static final ParameterType<String> TEXT = new ParameterType<>("I am a text");

  private ParameterType(T value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public T getValue() { return value; }
}
```

An important point is to make the constructor *private*, so it can't be invoked outside the class. This makes it a bit like an enum, in that the instances you define are the only instances.