# How to pass enum parameter in a method

Tags: java, parameters, enums

I've got 2 enum classes:

```
public enum Dogs
{
 JACKIE("Jackie"),
 BOBBY("Bobby");
}
```

and

```
public enum Cats
    {
     CHAN("Chan"),
     SPONGE("Sponge");
    }
```

And now I have a method in some other class where I want to pass enum as a parameter, so I could select either of them as per my needs.

```
public void findAnimal()
{
    List<Dogs> animals = Arrays.asList(Dogs.values());
    for (Dogs animal: animals)
    {
        rest of the code goes here
    }
}
```

So instead of providing hardcoded 'Dogs' I want to have a choice and pass parameter to the method, something like

```
public void (Enum enumAnimals)
{
    List<Enum> animals = Arrays.asList(Enum.values());
    for (Enum animal: animals)
}
```

But it doesnt accept it like this. Is it possible to pass generic type as "Enum'?

Comment: Your enums can implement a common interface. What do you want to do inside the for loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement enum with generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490485/how-to-implement-enum-with-generics)

Comment: This seems like a fundamental misuse of enums. I'd expect each of Chan, Sponge, etc. to be objects of a class, not enum members.

Comment: @BenR. R. Maybe I provided wrong examples of values, but I need the String values and not objects of a class. Those names will not change and will be used in many places in the application/code. That's why I need them to be constant.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou in 'for loop' I will do something like this:
input.typeName(animal.getName())
if(some condition)
{
String newName = animal.getName();
break;
}

Answer (score 5):

`Enum` is the *base* class for *all* enumerations so `Enum.values()` won't do anything. If you want to use multiple enums you could have them implement a common interface but even then you'd need to provide the instances. This *could* be done via reflection but I feel handing you that power now would be a receipe for disaster. In general enums are meant for static types like `AnimalType` and not for individual instances like a specific cat.

I'd suggest you have something like this (very simplified code to make it short):

```
enum AnimalType { 
  CAT,
  DOG;
}

class Animal {
  String name;
  AnimalType type;

  Animal( String n, AnimalType t) {
    name = n;
    type = t;
  }
}

Set<Animal> animals = ... //create a set
animals.add( new Animal( "Jackie", AnimalType.CAT ) );
animals.add( new Animal( "Chan", AnimalType.DOG) );
...
```

Note that many examples/tutorials that use a class like `Animal` focus more on inheritance, i.e. `class Cat extends Animal` etc. Reading between the lines of your question makes me feel that this is what you're actually after, not how to use enums.

Answer (score 1):

What you tried doesn't work largely because `Enum`, itself, doesn't have a `values` method. That's an implicit static method of the enum classes.

If you absolutely *have* to do this with separate `Dogs` and `Cats` enum types rather than doing it the way [Thomas suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55141581/157247), you could pass in the result of calling `values`:

```
obj.findAnimal(Dogs.values());
// or
obj.findAnimal(Cats.values());
```

then the method would be simply:

```
public void findAnimal(Enum[] animals) {
    for (Enum animal : animals) {
        System.out.println(animal);
    }
}
```

---

If *that* isn't suitable for some reason, it's also possible using [`Class.getEnumConstants`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants()): Rather than passing in `Dogs` or `Cats`, you'd pass in their class:

```
obj.findAnimal(Dogs.class);
// or
obj.findAnimal(Cats.class);
```

The method would be along these lines:

```
public void findAnimal(Class enumClass)
{
    Enum[] animals = (Enum[])enumClass.getEnumConstants();
    for (Enum animal: animals) {
        System.out.println(animal);
    }
}
```

(Thank you [Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo) for pointing out that my earlier version could be simplified markedly using `getEnumConstants`.)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure exactly what you want to do in this method but you can do something like this.

```
enum Dogs {
    JACKIE("Jackie"),
    BOBBY("Bobby");
    private final String name;

    Dogs(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

enum Cats {
    CHAN("Chan"),
    SPONGE("Sponge");
    private final String name;

    Cats(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

<E extends Enum<E>> void method(E e) {
    Enum<E>[] animals = e.getClass().getEnumConstants();
    for (Enum<E> animal : animals) {
        System.out.println(animal);
    }
}

private void test() {
    method(Dogs.BOBBY);
    method(Cats.CHAN);
}
```