# Very Specific Question about Enums (and maybe Type Parameters?)

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to make a server system, and have run into a problem. I have an enum called RType with an associated class:

```
package net.typho.utils;

public enum RType {
    STRING(String.class), INTEGER(Integer.class), BOOLEAN(Boolean.class);

    private Class<?> dataType;

    RType(Class<?> dataType) {
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }

    public Class<?> getDataType() {
        return dataType;
    }
}
```

(those three are just placeholders to make sure it's working)
I want to make a constructor that requires an RType, and something of the same class as the rtype's dataType. I could just make it throw an error, but I want IntelliJ Idea to flag it when I have the wrong class as the data. Could someone help me on this? Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490485/how-to-implement-enum-with-generics

Comment: That's not really what I'm asking here. A possibility to resolve my problem would be a method that returns an actual type parameter, not an instance of it, if you know how to do that.

Comment: Why do you need the `RType`? What do you get from it that you can't get from an instance of the "same class as the rtype's dataType"?

Comment: It's not possible with proper enums. The answer I linked to shows an alternative.

Comment: This is ***impossible*** to do with a single Java enum. I myself asked the same question to the creators of Java itself, and long story short, they said they understand, but that trying to add this ability that you want to enums requires more effort than it is worth, and therefore, it cannot and will not be done until their priorities change.

Comment: @shmosel has the link that shows what you should be doing until then. The only other option would be to use a `sealed interface` or something along those lines. But you asked for an enum, so my suggestion may be out of bounds.

Comment: See also https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8170351

Answer (score 3):

The values of a Java enum are always all of the same type.

If you want a "heterogeneous enum", you have to construct it yourself:

```
public final class RType<T> {
    public static final RType<String> STRING = new RType<>(String.class);
    public static final RType<Integer> INTEGER = new RType<>(Integer.class);
    public static final RType<Boolean> BOOLEAN = new RType<>(Boolean.class);

    private RType(Class<T> dataType) {
      this.dataType = dataType;
    }

    public Class<T> getDataType() {
        return dataType;
    }
}
```

Making the class final and the constructor private means that it can't be constructed outside the class, so the only instances of `RType` that exist are the ones referenced by `STRING`, `INTEGER` etc.

An enum is basically just a bunch of public static final members anyway, although it has some extra secret sauce to make it more enum-my.

Then, you can declare a constructor like you describe:

```
class YourClass<T> {
  YourClass(RType<T> rtype, T instance) { ... }
}
```

Comment: If that's the only way, then sure. But, is there a way to not have to write "public static final RType<> ... = new RType<>" every time?

Comment: @TheTypholorian If you declare them in an interface, you can omit `public static final`.

Comment: Do you have an example of that?

Comment: Don't declare them in an interface, because then you can't stop people creating new instances.

Comment: @TheTypholorian just write it out. Unless you are adding lots of these regularly, it's hardly burdensome.

Comment: Well, you *can* use an interface if you’re using recent Java. `public sealed interface RType<T> permits RTypeImpl { RType<String> STRING = impl(String.class);
RType<Integer> INTEGER = impl(Integer.class);
RType<Boolean> BOOLEAN = impl(Boolean.class);
private static <U> RType<U> impl(Class<U> type) { return new RTypeImpl<>(type) ;}
Class<T> datatype();
} /* not public */ record RTypeImpl<T>(Class<T> datatype) implements RType<T> {}` But I agree that there’s little benefit, compared to just writing it out.